# How to prove that G is 2-connected with this context? see details.

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be the graph on vertex set $$\{0, 1, 2, . . . , 100\}$$, with edges between i and j whenever $$\lvert i − j\lvert ∈ \{1, 4, 40, 61, 97, 100\}$$. Prove that G is 2-connected.
(It may be helpful to notice that 100 = 101−1, 97 = 101−4, and 61 = 101−40.)

Answer (score 1):

To prove $G$ is $2$-connected, it suffices to prove that there exists a cycle containing all vertices in $G$. The following one is a satisfying cycle:

$$
0 \leftrightarrow 1 \leftrightarrow 2 \leftrightarrow 3 \leftrightarrow \cdots \leftrightarrow 99 \leftrightarrow 100 \leftrightarrow 0
$$